# Jsoup always adding a <tbody> tag

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to parse http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketstats/gainerloser.php?optex=NSE&opttopic=topgainers&index=-2 with

```
Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);

Elements tableElements = document.select("table[class=tbldata14 bdrtpg]");
```

so that I can get all `<tr>` of `<table class="tbldata14 bdrtpg" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">` but it is appending an extra `<tbody>` which is not there in original html.

```
<table class="tbldata14 bdrtpg" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
 **<tbody>**
  <tr class="bggry"> 
   <th width="19%" align="left" class="brdrgtgry"><a href="/stocks/marketstats/gainerloser.php?optex=NSE&amp;opttopic=topgainers&amp;sort=sc_comp&amp;order=" class="bl_12"><b>Company Name</b></a></th> 
   <th class="brdrgtgry" align="left">High</th> 
   <th class="brdrgtgry" align="left">Low</th> .....
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `document.select("table[class='tbldata14 bdrtpg'] tr");`.

Comment: [This question seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791867/jsoup-parser-issue) - Use the XML parser instead of the HTML one?

Comment: It worked with 'document.select("table[class=tbldata14 bdrtpg] tr");' Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
document.select("table[class=tbldata14 bdrtpg] tr");
```

It will select the actual content of the table.